# fire action when post is being edited as well as saved?

Tags: posts, functions, hooks

I'm trying to fire some code when a page is edited and/or saved. This code works:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'add_promoted_meta_data' );
function add_promoted_meta_data( $post_id ) {
   echo '<h1>test</h1>';
}
```

...but this code does not:

```
add_action( 'edit_post', 'add_promoted_meta_data' );
function add_promoted_meta_data( $post_id ) {
   echo '<h1>test</h1>';
}
```

What action would I use to combine the functionality? I ultimately need to fire code upon creating or editing a post?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for the [`save_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) action says:

> `save_post` is an action triggered whenever a post or page is created or updated, which could be from an import, post/page edit form, xmlrpc, or post by email.

So, you should only need the `save_post` action to run the desired code when the post is changed.

Comment: Yes, but it is not firing when editing. Only when I create and then save.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the `save_post` action only triggers when the post's content has actually changed. Are you actually editing the content when testing this or just hitting the Update button without changing any content?

Comment: I thought of that as well. I'm adding content. It's still not working.

Comment: Are there any other plugins installed? One of them could be interfering with the `save_post` action.

Comment: I've disabled all plugins and it still does not work. When I go to create a post, it fires before I hit publish. I would imagine if I were to update a post, it would fire before I actually press update. Just by visiting that page.

Comment: It definitely shouldn't fire before you hit Publish, unless an auto-save is triggering it, maybe?

Comment: For some reason the echo was throwing the error.